# red5 0.9 on Windows - Java Problems on build

Tags: java, flash, eclipse, red5

so I've installed red5 0.9, I've installed jdk 1.6 update 22. I've set my environment variables correctly, installed eclipse galileo for java ee developers, tortoise svn, and then ivyde and subclipse plugins for eclipse. I then created a folder called red5_server, and did the svn checkout. When I try to import the red5_server, I get the java problem:

The project was not built due to "Could not delete '/red5_server/bin/org'.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent

Do you have any idea what could cause this? Also, while it was attempting to build, an error flashed on the screen and quickly disappears. I was only able to read it by removing the project and importing it over and over again until I was able to react quick enough to screen-capture the error. It says:

'Ivy resolve job of ivy.xml in 'red5_server has encountered a problem. Error while resolving the ivy instance for ivy.xml in 'red5_server': Unrecognized variables in the Ivy settings file ${workspace_loc:red5_server/ivysettings.xml}

Any idea what this could be? Thanks in advance!

Also, when I remove the project and try it again, I get the same ivy.xml error and isntead of getting the one java problem, i get over 5000. Any ideas? My head is spinning over here.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this on a freshly reformatted computer with the same results and with every version of red5.

All of the errors are Java Problems of the same type:

ApplicationAdapter cannot be resolved to a type    Application.java

or,

The import org.red5.server.adapter cannot be resolved    Application.java

or,

log cannot be resolved    Application.java

or,

The method getName() is undefined for the type Application    Application.java

Am I missing some essential file or path?

Comment: Did you find a solution??? This is happening to me to and i'm loosing my mind...if you can tell me anything it will be a very good start... thanks man :)

Comment: its ridiculous to ask you now.. have you found out any solution? I have spent one month trying to set up developer environment in eclipse for red5...